# www do not equal no www

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I have a website with dns pointing to my own server. the website WITH www.mysite.com lead to the right site, but the address mysite.com lead to a publicity site that I DONT CONTROL

I like to make www.mysite.com and the mysite.com lead to the same DNS

Can i make it with .htaccess or with google analitic, but since i dont know the resolver that lead me to the bizzare page i dont have control on that

As request : 
http://www.demolition-st-chrysostome.org/ (ok)
http://demolition-st-chrysostome.org/ (no)

Comment: waht's the site url. Maybe we can help you.

Comment: How exactly do you have control over the subdomain if you don't have control of the domani itself?

Comment: What do you mean "do not control"? It jumps to a third party somedomain.com, or displays mysite.com? Who manages the DNS settings? If you have access, could you list them?

Comment: Points to the same site for me, works now?

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is to add an A record for 'mysite.com' in your nameserver that points to the public IP address of your web server. You have to do this from the same place where you've set the IP address for the www subdomain.

If 'mysite.com' is pointing somewhere out of your control, there is no way you can do anything useful with .htaccess, before you add/change the A record in the nameserver.

---

**UPDATE:**

Further to your edit, it looks like your DNS records are fine, and both are working. If you have recently modified your nameservers, they may take a few hours to work correctly because of DNS caching.

Comment: and have the www cname point to the A record.

Comment: @Christopher Mahan: why should we use CNAME in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If mysite.com is under your control, you should put both mysite.com and www.mysite.com in DNS pointing to your server.

It might be that a provider set this up for you and they forgot to put both entries in DNS?
In that case you should get in contact with them.